Manga where the main character, his sister, and two of her friends are transported to another world, but the MC was transported by mistake
The main character (MC), his sister, and her two friends are all transported but the MC was mistakenly transported. The MC is transported somewhere in some forest when the other three are elsewhere. The gods that accidentally transported him meet him and give him some perks to make up for accidentally transporting him. He lives without interacting with his sister in the forest, but eventually ventures out.

Were the sister's friends girls, boys, or one of each?

They were one of each.

This is I Got Sent to Another World, but It's in the Mountains. In Reaction, I Choose Comfort Over Strength.

A protagonist enjoyed his Isekai life by stubbornly doing everything at his own pace. Abundantly surrounded by misanthropes, he tried to redo his life and have an amicable personality… Let’s leave it at that. When starting over with life, returning to one’s mental age was not guaranteed. Probably.

The story begins with the protagonist driving his older sister and her two friends to a camp ground. They're suddenly taken to another world as part of a hero summoning - but the protagonist is completely unaware of this, as he is separated from his sister and gets lost in the wilderness. A god appears at the end of the first chapter and explains the situation: his sister is a hero, he was accidentally included, he can't go back.

The god and several other gods then bestow gifts on him to make up for it. He lives out his life in the new world, avoiding his sister and they did not get along.


That's it. Thank you.

@Iruoma You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as accepted, which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the tour.
